# iFrame srcdoc - possible to use dynamic content / regex? HTML5

Tags: regex, html, iframe

I know the srcdoc in iframes is relatively new (hence why I've been unable to find much iformation on it), but I've been wondering (and hoping!) if it's possible to use it dynamically, i.e. to take a section of a website and display it in an iframe?

For example, say I'd want to take just the breaking news section of the BBC website where the content keeps changing and put that in an iframe, just that bit, is the srcdoc able to do that?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, and this is also not what `srcdoc` is designed for. The `srcdoc` attribute is available in WebKit browsers to set the content of an `iframe` rather than have it load a separate page from the server. Learn more about it at [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_srcdoc.asp).

If you have an iframe with a page from another server (like the BBC website) then you have no way of accessing that page to extract or manipulate its contents because of the browser's same-origin policy.

The way to do it is having a server-side script downloading the BBC page, manipulating it and sending it to the client.

Comment: Thanks - not what I was hoping for, but I'll check out a PHP way of doing it instead! Cheers for the heads up!